# SyntaxError: Unexpected token *

Tags: javascript, node.js, import

I want to import code from the module BodyPix but I keep getting the following error message:

```
import * as bodyPix from '@tensorflow-models/body-pix';
       ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token *
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:718:23)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:785:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:641:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:556:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:837:10)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11
```

I've tried different ways of importing but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Have you `npm install`ed the module?

Comment: Did you try `import bodyPix from '@tensorflow-models/body-pix';` ?

Comment: @shaochuancs the error is thrown before the module's name is even read.

Comment: Doesn't Node require some special steps to enable ES2015 module import/export?

Answer (score 4):

CommonJS - style import should work:

```
const bodyPix = require('@tensorflow-models/body-pix');
```

Answer (score 3):

That's because current Node.js does not support `import * as XXX` syntax (at least in `v10.15.3` on my computer).

To run this unsupported statement, you need to save the Node.js file with modules as `.mjs` extension and run it like:

`node --experimental-modules index.mjs`

Answer (score 3):

Node.js does not support import in this syntax either save the file with modules as `.mjs` extension
and run like this

```
node --experimental-modules index.mjs
```

as mentioned by shaochuancs
**OR**
another alternative is to use a transpiler. That converts modern JavaScript to older versions for you. Good options are **TypeScript, Babel, and Rollup**.